# Excel VBA - Select Case - Multiple Test Expressions

Tags: vba, excel, select, case

I am attempting to write a Select Case Statement that looks at a range of values throughout the A column  and then preforms the statements.

So far I can get my select case statement to work for row A2 but I can't get it to work with a range of values without giving me a, 'Type Mismatch Error'.

Working

```
Select Case range("A2").Value

Case "01"
    range("G2").Value = "Admin"
    range("I2").Value = "None"
    range("J2").Value = "None"
    range("K2").Value = "None"
    range("H2").Value = "No Affiliation"
    range("T2").Value = "99999"
```

Not Working (***Type Mismatch Error***)

```
Select Case Range ("A2:A1000").Value

Case "01"
    range("G2").Value = "Admin"
    range("I2").Value = "None"
    range("J2").Value = "None"
    range("K2").Value = "None"
    range("H2").Value = "No Affiliation"
    range("T2").Value = "99999"

Case "A"
    range("G2").Value = "Dealer"
    range("I2").Value = "None"
    range("J2").Value = "None"
    range("K2").Value = "None"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to step through each cell in the range instead, "A2:A1000" will return an array, not a value.

```
Sub SO()

Dim rNum As Long

For rNum = 2 To 1000

   Select Case Range("A" & rNum).Value
      Case "01"
         Range("G" & rNum).Value = "Admin"
         Range("I" & rNum).Value = "None"
         Range("J" & rNum).Value = "None"
         Range("K" & rNum).Value = "None"
         Range("H" & rNum).Value = "No Affiliation"
         Range("T" & rNum).Value = "99999"

      Case "A"
         Range("G" & rNum).Value = "Dealer"
         Range("I" & rNum).Value = "None"
         Range("J" & rNum).Value = "None"
         Range("K" & rNum).Value = "None"

      Case Else
         '// Do something else...
   End Select

Next rNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!! This will also help me step through the process of incrementing the other range values as well!